# SQLITE trigger compilation even when condition is not working

Tags: sqlite

I have 1 table (TBLVPPEDIDO) and 1 Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_UPD_TESTE
BEFORE UPDATE of cdstatuspedido on TBLVPPEDIDO
FOR EACH ROW
when new.cdstatuspedido = 2
begin 
 SELECT RAISE(ABORT,'ERRO AO FECHAR PEDIDO, LIGUE PARA A SOUZA ROXO!!!!!!'); 
end
```

The error should only fire when the cdstatuspedid field equals 2, but not working,

Could someone please help me solve it?

Comment: Could you give some example data and show a query that is triggering it that shouldn't?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query